# onRestoreInstanceState of SimpleCursorApdater

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter, screen-rotation

How to save/restore state of `ListView` which attached to a `CursorAdapter`? Example:

I have a Android `Activity` with 3 `ListView`: Countries, Regions, Cities.

They are attached to 3 `SimpleCursorApdater`: `CountryAdapter`, `RegionAdapter`, `CityAdapter`.

- chose a item on the Countries List will filter items of the Regions List by changing query condition of the `RegionAdapter`
- chose a item on the Regions List will filter items of the Cities List by changing query condition of the `CityAdapter`

Pseudo code:

```
void countryList_onItemSelected() {
    regionsAdapter.getFilter().filter(countryId);
}
void regionList_onItemSelected() {
    cityAdapter.getFilter().filter(regionId);
}

Cursor regionAdapter_FilterQueryProvider_runQuery(countryId) {
    Cursor cur = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().
            query("Select * from Region where countryId = "+countryId);
    return cur;
}

Cursor cityAdapter_FilterQueryProvider_runQuery(regionId) {
    Cursor cur = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().
            query("select * from City where regionId = "+regionId);
    return cur;
}
```

When the `onRestoreInstanceState()` is called, the `cityListView` is empty because the 2 `runQuery()` methods have not been terminated yet. So I cannot go straight:

```
void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    ...
    savedCitySelection = state.getInt("citySelectedItemPosition")
    cityListView.setSelection(savedCitySelection); // <= NOOO! the cityListView is empty
}
```

**Question: 
How can I save/restore the state of these 3 lists with `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState().`**

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a `Loader`.

Then when the loading is finished and you swap the cursor in you can call `smoothScrollToPosition(int position)`* on the `ListView`.

CommonsWare has a good CursorLoader based on the support library here:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex

**(Note: smoothScrollToPosition requires Android 2.2)*